# WM_MOUSEWHEEL и точное позиционирование курсора в окне

Tags: c++, c, winapi

При получении сообщения `WM_MOUSEWHEEL` возвращаемые данные макросами `GET_X_LPARAM` и `GET_Y_LPARAM`, отдают координаты мыши в рабочем пространстве, не в окне, даже если окно не находится под курсором.

Какими средствами можно подсчитать позиционирование мыши относительно пользовательской области окна?

Пытался получить размеры границ окна (не клиентской области) извлекая данные  методом `GetSystemMetrics`, но как-то не зашло, или я не те данные извлекал.

Использовал следующие макросы для получения размеров не клиентской области:

```
SM_CXBORDER
SM_CYCAPTION
```

Но при расчете данные были не корректны:

```
Данные курсора во время перемещения, последняя точка.

MousePos: X =799, Y= 0
EventType: MouseMove
CtrlModKey: None

Данные курсора относительно последней точки, прокрутка колеса мыши в последней точке.

MousePos: X =1082, Y= 95
EventType: Wheel
CtrlModKey: None


Данные расчета позиции курсора относительно окна.

IsInRgn result is: X = 806, Y = 8
MouseWheel Down
```

Метод определения коллизии для объекта и курсора во время прокрутки:

```
bool MousePosition::IsInRgn(RECT & rect, RECT & wndRect)
{
    int border = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXBORDER);
    int capt = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYCAPTION);

    int xm = wndRect.left + border;
    int ym =  wndRect.top + capt + border;

    bool result = ((x - xm) >= rect.left && x - ((x - xm) <= rect.right) && ((y - ym) >= rect.top && (y - ym) <= rect.bottom));

    printf("\n%s result is: X = %d, Y = %d\n", __func__, (x - xm), (y - ym));

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для преобразования координат между окнами можно использовать функцию [`MapWindowPoints`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145046(v=vs.85).aspx):

```
::HWND const in_window{}; // рабочий стол
::HWND const out_window{my_window_handle}; // целевое окно
::POINT point{GET_X_LPARAM(lparam), GET_Y_LPARAM(lparam)};
::UINT points_count{1};
::MapWindowPoints(in_window, out_window, &point, points_count);
```

Comment: Отлично, все работает как часы!